# Writing QGIS Action which opens PDF from server

Tags: qgis, pdf

I need to open a PDF from an action in QGis.
The PDF rests on a server, not local.

So far I tried this (as Python):

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import QUrl; 
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import QWebView;  
myWV = QWebView(None); 
myWV.load(QUrl(('https://myserver.com/[% "path" %])); 
myWV.show()
```

This just opens an empty window. It works with a png.

How do I do that?

Comment: You are missing a single quote in your string for a start. `myWV.load(QUrl('https://myserver.com/[% "path" %]')); `

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `QWebView` does support PDF though the systems PDF web plugin however it seems a bit hit and miss for me.

You can open the report in the default web browser using the **Open** command

[image]