# Opening PDF file using QGIS

Tags: qgis, pdf, hyperlink

At this time I not found a clear procedure (step by step) on how to open a pdf file **using QGIS 3.20**.

I added a new field in my table where I put the pdf file name (one time only the file name, another time including path+file name, with or without quotes). In the attributes I put the widget as attachment and as path I put the pre-defined path, flagging the relative path respect the project path. I don't know if the above procedure was correct. The problem is to define a correct action.

How do I open a PDF file using QGIS?

Comment: to open a pdf in a web browser use 'open' in the action settings https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/69275/how-to-write-a-qgis-action-which-opens-a-pdf-from-a-server

Comment: If you are using windows you can add  the following command to the open action: cmd /c [%filename%] where filename is your column with the absolute path to the PDF. That will open the PDF with the connected app, Acrobat for example...this works also for word or open office documents

Comment: Ho provato entrambe le soluzione ma sembrano non funzionare. Nel campo degli attibuti ho inserito il nome del file con l'intero percorso "D:\LAVORI\TITOLI MINERARI\Italia-Pozzi e Titoli (dati per QGis)\Log finali disponibili\Pozzo ZZZZ 001.pdf". In Action ho riportato la stringa cmd /d [% "Well_pdf" %] dove Well_pdf è il nome della colonna contenente i dati e nel Modulo Attributi ho riportato Tipo widget = Allegato, mentre il percorso è impostato come D:/LAVORI/TITOLI MINERARI/Italia-Pozzi e Titoli (dati per QGis)\Log finali disponibili\. Dove ho sbagliato?

Comment: English please ...

Comment: I've tried both solutions but they don't seem to work. In the field of the attributes I put the name of the file with the entire path "D:\LAVORI\TITOLI MINERARI\Italia-Pozzi e Titoli (dati per QGis)\Log finali disponibili\Pozzo ZZZZ 001.pdf". In Action I reported the string cmd / d [% "Well_pdf"%] where Well_pdf is the name of the column containing the data and in the Attributes Module I reported Widget type = Attachment, while the path is set as D:\LAVORI\TITOLI MINERARI\Italia-Pozzi e Titoli (dati per QGis)\Log finali disponibili\. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Make sure there is *no* quote or double quotes around the path in the attribute table. Then having an action of type `open` with the code `[%"Well_pdf"%]` should work. Make sure you re-select the action to be performed after having modifed it.